# How to assign "empty" to a list position (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, assign

I'm trying to modify my `listt`:

```
listt = [[1, 4], [11, 24], [11123, 6624], [3, 4]]
lvl = 11
n = 50
for z in listt:
    if z[0]==lvl:
        if z[1] > n:
            z[1]=n
        elif z[1] < n:
            z[1]=None
```

As you can see I'm trying to replace the second number of the position `z` in `listt` if `lvl` is equal to the 1rt number of `listt` (in the same position) by `n`.

If the second number is smaller than `n` I want to assign the position `z[1] = "empty"...` so it would be like: `[...,[11,],...]` or something like this, but it's printing this:

```
11 None
```

Comment: You are looking for `del z[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `del z[1]` instead:

```
listt = [[1, 4], [11, 24], [11123, 6624], [3, 4]]
lvl = 11
n = 50
for z in listt:     
    if z[0]==lvl:
        if z[1] > n:
            z[1]=n
        elif z[1] < n:
            del z[1]
```

Now:

```
>>> listt
[[1, 4], [11], [11123, 6624], [3, 4]]
```